# Oembed Vine Android webview- ssl error

Tags: android, ssl, webview, oembed, vine

I am trying to embed `Vine` into an android application using a `webview` and calling the vine ombed api to get the HTML to display in the `webview`. I am currently getting the following error

`https://vine.co/v/MwrDbBbbwIK/embed/simple net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`

I know this is some sort of ssl certificate error. I am able to get this to display correctly in `Safari` but not in `Chrome` or in my android `webview`. Is there anyway to get around this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()       
{
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
    }
});
```